# WPF change text property on TextBlock in ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-3.5

I have TabControl and I have a plan to generate dynamicaly TabItems and fill up with ControlTemplate.

ControlTemplate:

```
<Window.Resources>
     <ControlTemplate x:Key="Qtemp" TargetType="Control">
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="yesButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Visibility="Visible" Name="Normal" Source="/TabItemTemplate;component/Images/yes.png" />
                    <Image Visibility="Hidden" Name="Pressed" Source="/TabItemTemplate;component/Images/yes_p.png" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Pressed" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="noButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Visibility="Visible" Name="Normal" Source="/TabItemTemplate;component/Images/no.png" />
                    <Image Visibility="Hidden" Name="Pressed" Source="/TabItemTemplate;component/Images/no_p.png" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Pressed" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="circleButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse>
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Grid>
                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Ellipse Grid.Row="1" Margin="-1024,-75,0,0" Name="progress_bar" Fill="#FF01325E" Width="424" Height="424" StrokeThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                <Ellipse.Clip>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,212,424"/>
                </Ellipse.Clip>
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            </Ellipse>
            <Grid Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" >
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/TabItemTemplate;component/Images/Q_bg.png" />
                </Grid.Background>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Name="QBody" Width="400" Margin="-120,-100,0,0" Foreground="#FF333333" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="28" TextAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" />
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button  Width="172" Height="172"  Name="BT_yes" Template="{StaticResource yesButton}" Click="BT_NextQ" />
                <Button  Width="172" Height="172"  Name="BT_no" Margin="0,20,0,0" Template="{StaticResource noButton}" Click="BT_NextQ" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Image Grid.Row="2" Source="/TabItemTemplate;component/Images/toolbar.png" />
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Width="56" Height="56" Tag="/TabItemTemplate;component/Images/home.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,0,0,15" Template="{StaticResource circleButton}" />
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Width="56" Height="56" Tag="/TabItemTemplate;component/Images/back.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,0,0,15" Template="{StaticResource circleButton}" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

In XAML:

```
   <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="navTab" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
        <TabItem Name="tabItem1a" Header="static">
             <Control Template="{StaticResource Qtemp}" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

CS file:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)


{
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
        TabItem newTab = new TabItem();
        Control newControl = new Control();
        newControl.Template = (ControlTemplate)FindResource("Qtemp");

        //TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)newControl.Template.FindName("Qbody", newControl);
        //tb.Text = "TEST" + i.ToString();
        newTab.Header = "Dynamic"+i.ToString();
        newTab.Name = "Question" + i.ToString();
        newTab.Content = newControl;
        navTab.Items.Add(newTab);

}
}
```

In template I have TextBlock "Qbody" and Ellipse "progress_bar".
Im trying add text to "Qbody" and RorateTransform Angle for "progress_bar" but I cant get access to any controls in template.

I tried:

`TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)newControl.Template.FindName("Qbody", newControl);`

But it returns `null`.

Can anyone help me with it. 
I dont know what im doing wrong. 
Is any other way to set these two controls.

Answer (score 1):

you have this marked as mvvm, but what you are doing violates mvvm principles.  Your progress bar and textbox should be bound to your viewmodel, then you can access thier properties there.

Your controls are null because they have not been created yet.

But if you want to use code behind you need to access the controls in the apply template event  of the framework element (Tab Control)

[Framework ApplyTemplate Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.applytemplate.aspx)

Cheers

EDIT 1:

You have to implement iNotifyPropertyChanged for the UI to be made "aware" of changes to the properties in the viewmodel.  You would raise this event for every iteration of your property counter.

Also, the scope of what you need cannot be covered in one answer.  I recommend reading more about MVVM and WPF and maybe use an existing framework to help like MVVM-Light or Caliburn.Micro.

Comment: Thanks for some ideas I had no idea how to start even. I will create ViewModel with some properties. I have one more question: if I create ViewModel and properties i.e. TextBloc_body and EllipseAngle and bind them to template what happen if I change it for every loop literation. Template bind them at moment when I assign value to property and stay with the same value or all will get value of last property change?

Comment: Property in ViewModel dont working. I mean it working but all TextBlock have text of last literation change property. How I can do to TextBlock on each tabitem has different text?